# Creating a dr-mercola tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

**Subset of: [Should we allow "name" tags?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243/should-we-allow-name-tags)

---

I receive Dr. Mercola's newsletter and have used his posts to create [a number of posts](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=mercola). I wondered about creating a [dr-mercola](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dr-mercola) tag. I'm open to suggestions either way. He's the originator and promotor of many various food and drug related claims and has a wide audience. Thus, I could see tagging posts that begin with him or are substantiated by his work. On the other hand, if it isn't seen as helpful, I'll leave it alone.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Related: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4983/38337

Answer (score 1):

Mercola has peddled all kinds of pseudoscience, he doesn't seem to be very selective but rehashes everything that he can find. I don't think it would be a useful classification.

But our tagging in general is pretty random, so there is certainly room for improvement.

Comment: I can definitely see that take. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, in March 2012, I created a [joseph-mercola](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseph-mercola) tag, and added several questions to it, without reference to this question. It was only just brought to my attention.

Answer (score -1):

#### 12 years later, [joseph-mercola](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseph-mercola) and [dr-mercola](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dr-mercola) each have 0 questions.

The answer for now is that this tag is not necessary. A more general discussion about the criteria for making tags for individuals was started here: [What are the criteria for having an entire tag just for one person?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4983/38337)

Comment: I don't cme to the same conclusion? I haven't been active on this site in maybe 10yrs, so me asking about creating the tag suggests it didn't exist. I see they haven't been used, but "mercola" yields [22 results](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=mercola), which is more than almost everyone in every example list in the question you linked to. A question asked doesn't mean it's answered... the top current answer says "So, I guess the line I would propose is 'There is only one question, and it isn't likely that more will be added in the short term.'" Mercola isn't in that bucket.

Comment: I don't know what that commenter Hendy (also probably the downvoter) is complaining about. What an unusual comment.

Comment: I am not the downvoter. You are saying the reason the tag is not needed is due to no questions having the tag. Then you link to a meta discussion asking for the criteria for creating a tag, and I cited a statement from the current top answer. So, for evidence on "does mercola deserve a tag," (a) that answer says more than one question justifies (mercola has 22) and (b) mercola has more than almost all other famous people cited (assuming they are in the running for having tags). Funny enough, I found your answer unusual.

Comment: I'm sorry for suggesting that you were "probably the downvoter". Later I realized that a user that has exclusively or pretty much exclusively downvoted my content across the network since around 2019, voted 4 times yesterday, and my 3 answers (all now with -1 score) and my question, all had new votes on them. **As for your first comment**, the opening sentence/question was highly unusual in my opinion. The next sentence didn't make sense to me except for the part about you not being active in 10 years (although you were active enough to see my question within a day). The rest is so confusing.

Comment: We're probably crossing paths because your answer isn't very clear. I see it as asserting: "because there are no questions with this tag, no tag is warranted." After reading the linked meta post, I'm stating: I do not come to the same conclusion.

I added I haven't been on in 10yrs, as apparently 10yrs ago, I was asking the community of a dr-mercola tag was warranted. I have no idea if it was created, if it already existed, etc. But point is: say I went and tagged the 22 mercola related posts with dr-mercola... does that change your answer?

Comment: I thought "I don't cme to the same conclusion?" meant that you did come to the same conclusion as me, otherwise I don't see why you would be asking it as a question. The rest of the comment had similar problems. Even the first sentence wasn't properly proofread.

Comment: Thanks for the productive discussion!